# "Make sure the service address is correct and enable CORS if needed. (https://enable-cors.org)" error in .NET web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, telerik, blazor-hybrid

I'm trying to implement Telerik web report designer to blazer .NET MAUI hybrid app, and it keep giving above mentioned error when I try to view the created. report. But I have already add Cors to the app.

```
{
    ReportingEngineConfiguration = sp.GetService<IConfiguration>(),
    HostAppId = "newcumstomreportAPI",
    Storage = new FileStorage(),
    ReportSourceResolver = new UriReportSourceResolver(
        Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Reports"))
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IReportDesignerServiceConfiguration>(sp => new ReportDesignerServiceConfiguration
{
    DefinitionStorage = new FileDefinitionStorage(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Reports")),
    SettingsStorage = new FileSettingsStorage(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Telerik Reporting")),
    ResourceStorage = new ResourceStorage(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Resources"))
});

builder.Services.AddCors();

var app = builder.Build();




app.UseStaticFiles();
//app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.UseCors(builder =>
                builder.WithOrigins("*")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
            );

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

I'm expecting identify the error and suggest me a solution.

Comment: Have  you tried to replace your `builder.WithOrigins("*") with builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:800", "https://YouractualSite Name");`?

Comment: Please try by setting specific origin if that error pop ups changes.

Comment: i have tried it. But not working.

Comment: Your web api's configuration is ok, The issue may be on telerik, Maybe you can check this [Docs](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/embedding-reports/host-the-report-engine-remotely/telerik-reporting-rest-services/asp.net-web-api-implementation/add-rest-web-api-to-web-application) to find the issue.